# Issues sending multiple images on Flutter using Multipart and Dio

Tags: flutter, dart, multipartform-data, dio

I'm trying to send multiple files that came from Multi Image Picker pluggin on Flutter to my server, for this I'm trying to use Dio to send it. But the Multipart tag isn't uploading the files too. How to proceed?

```
    Future<Response> _uploadFile() async {

    var catUpload = jsonEncode(incluirCategoriasParaUpload());
    final FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "action": 'add_Anuncio',
      "filial_id": "1",
      "titulo": tituloControler.text,
      "descricao": descricaoControler.text,
      "categorias": catUpload
    });

    for (var val in listaImagensParaUpload) {
      ByteData byteData = await val.getByteData();
      Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      formData.files.add(
          MapEntry("arquivos",
              await MultipartFile.fromBytes(pngBytes, filename: "teste")
          )
      );
    }

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.interceptors.add(alice.getDioInterceptor());
    return await dio
        .post(URL_WS + WS_PAGE,
        data: formData,
        options: Options(method: 'POST', responseType: ResponseType.json))
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 2000));
//        .catchError(dioError);


  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You must declare as toList() this for loop.

Here is an example how to make it.

```
formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'id': '1',
  'title': 'myTitle',
  'files': [
            for (var file in listFiles)
            {await MultipartFile.fromFile(item.path, filename: 'fileName')}
             .toList()
           ]
});
```

I am usign Dio library working with MultiPartFile.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this solution with dio and image_picker dependency. And it will definitely work. I have spent 2 days for this solution.

```
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
"name": "Max",
"location": "Paris",
"age": 21,
"image[]": [
await MultipartFile.fromFile(
  _imageFile.path,
),
await MultipartFile.fromFile(
  _imageFile.path,
),
], 
});

print(FormData1().then((value) {
print(value);
 }));
response = await dio.post(

"http://143.110.244.110/radius/frontuser/eventsubmitbutton",
data: formData,
onSendProgress: (received, total) {
if (total != -1) {
  print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + '%');
}
},
);
 print(response);
```